# how it is returning 0, 1 or -1 affects the end results of array_udiff_assoc()

Tags: php, arrays

I know what it is and what it does what I don't understand how it works specially with spaceship operator "<=>".

I'm currently working on some features for spatie/laravel-activitylog and the main function that does all of the heavy lifting is `array_udiff_assoc()` with the said spaceship operator.

My question is how it is returning 0, 1 or -1 affects the end results even in other array_* functions like _diff or _intersect? it so confusing and I only asked here because I wasted many many hours searching online without any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#:%7E:text=Spaceship%20operator%20%C2%B6,PHP%27s%20usual%20type%20comparison%20rules.) compares two values and returns an integer based on those two values. The output integer is:

- 0 if both values are equal
- -1 if the first value is less than the second value
- 1 if the first value is greater than the second value

```
echo 1 <=> 1; // 0
echo 1 <=> 2; // -1
echo 2 <=> 1; // 1
```

The [array_udiff_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff-assoc.php) function uses the spaceship operator to see if the values are equal. Specifically the
last parameter passed to it is like this`callback ( mixed $a, mixed $b ) : int`. The resulting integer has to be:

- 0 if `$a` is equal to `$b`
- -1 (or less) if `$a` is less than `$b`
- 1 (or higher) if `$a` is greater than `$b`

These rules match exactly with how the spaceship operator behaves. So using the operator here will result in very little code doing relatively much work.

*Sidenote:because this function is only checking for differences it only really matters if the callback returns equal or not equal. The greater or less than parts don't matter as both of them get filtered out anyway.*